# R like str() function in matlab/GNU Octave

Tags: r, matlab, octave

I'd like to be able to view the structure of objects in Matlab/GNU Octave the same way as I do in R (using the [`str()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/str.html) function). Is there a function that does this? An example task would be returning nr rows and cols in matrix, but also all the arguments for a given function.

I'm aware that I could use both [`size()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/size.html) and [`help()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/help.html?searchHighlight=help) (but not for [function files](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_12.html#SEC95)) separately to get this information.

Comment: did you try the [dataframe package](http://octave.sourceforge.net/dataframe/) for Octave? It is modelled after the data.frame class for R. After this, just typing the name of your variable will pretty print its contents kinda like R.

Comment: @carandraug Do you have the specific command to get the `str()` or `dim()` of an object in Octave. I installed the package: `pkg install -forge dataframe` and loaded it `pkg load dataframe`, and I am trying now to find the dimensions or structure of a datset `data.mat` in the workspace. I believe it's a structure consisting of a `4 x 372,550` numerical matrix; two `4 x 46,568` numerical matrices, and a `256 x 1` character matrix. To get this info I had to scroll through many pages of the printout of `data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several useful functions for displaying some information about Matlab objects (I can't say anything about Octave compatibility), but I'm not sure they'll provide the same detail as R's `str()`. You can display all of the methods of a class with the [`methods`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/methods.html) function, e.g.:

```
methods('MException')
```

which returns

```
Methods for class MException:

 addCause       getReport      ne             throw          
 eq             isequal        rethrow        throwAsCaller  

 Static methods:

 last
```

The [`what`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html) function will return similar results. Or `methods` can be used on an object of a given class:

```
ME = MException('Test:test','Testing');
methods(ME)
```

Similarly, you can view the properties with [`properties`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/properties.html) and the events with [`events`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/events.html).