# Equivalent of R's str in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

In `R`, the function `str` gives more information about the structure of an `R` object. Is there an equivalent in Matlab?

Comment: Related question from before is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815578/r-like-str-function-in-matlab-gnu-octave

Comment: thanks, did not see this in my search