# How to explore the structure and dimensions of an object in Octave?

Tags: r, database, matlab, data-structures, octave

Im Matlab the [`properties` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19816012/4089351) sounds like a possible valid equivalent to commands in R that acquaint you with a particular object in the working environment, providing information as to its structure (data.frame, matrix, list, vector) and type of variables (character, numeric) (for example, with the R command `str()`), dimensions (using perhaps the call `dim()`), and names of the variables (`names()`).

However, this function is not operational in Octave:

```
>> properties(data)
warning: the 'properties' function is not yet implemented in Octave
```

I installed the package `dataframe` as suggested in a comment on the post linked above:

`pkg install -forge dataframe` and loaded it `pkg load dataframe`

But I can't find a way of getting a summary of the structure and dimensions of a datset `data.mat` in the workspace.

I believe it's a structure consisting of a 4 x 372,550 numerical matrix; two 4 x 46,568 numerical matrices, and a 256 x 1 character matrix. To get this info I had to scroll through many pages of the printout of data.

This info is not available on the Octave IDE, where I get:

```
Name      Class     Dimensions
data      struc     1 x 1
```

a far cry from the complexity of the object `data`.

What is the smart way of getting some this information about an object in the workspace in Octave?

---

Following up on the first answer provided, here is what I get with `whos`:

```
>> whos
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        data        1x1                    7452040  struct

Total is 1 element using 7452040 bytes
```

This is not particularly informative about what `data` really contains. In fact, I just found out a way to extract the names inside `data`:

```
>> fieldnames(data)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = testData
  [2,1] = trainData
  [3,1] = validData
  [4,1] = vocab
}
```

Now if I call

```
>> size(data)
ans =

   1   1
```

the output is not very useful. On the other hand, knowing the names of the matrices within `data` I can do

```
>> size(data.trainData)
ans =

        4   372550
```

which is indeed informative.

Comment: The output of `[1 1]` for a scalar struct is useful. It tells you that you have a scalar struct and not a struct array with multiple elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you type the name of the variable, you'll see information about it. In your case it's a struct, so it'll tell you the field names. Relevant functions are: `size`, `ndims`, `class`, `fieldnames`, etc.

```
size(var)
class(var)
```

etc.

You refer to `.mat`. Maybe you have a MAT-file, which you can load with `load filename`. Once loaded you can examine and use the variables in the file.

```
whos
```

prints simple information on the variables in memory, most useful to see what variables exist.

---

Following up on your edited question. This works in Octave:

```
for s=fieldnames(data)'
   s=s{1};
   tmp=data.(s);
   disp([s,' - ',class(tmp),' - ',mat2str(size(tmp))])
end
```

It prints basic information of each of the members of the struct. It does assume that `data` is a 1x1 struct array. Note that a struct can be an array:

```
data(2).testData = [];
```

Causes your `data` struct to be a 2x1 array. This is why `size(data)` is relevant. `class` is also important (it's shown in the output of `whos`. Variables can be of type `double` (normal arrays), and other numeric types, `logical`, `struct`, `cell` (an array of arrays), or a custom class that you can write yourself.

I highly recommend reading an introductory text on MATLAB/Octave, as it works very differently from R. It's not just a different flavor of language, it's a whole different world.

Comment: Thank you. Unless I call the specific matrices within `data` (see edited OP), it doesn't quite work out.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I just tried this in Octave, indeed it prints all the matrices inside the `struct`. MATLAB does not do this if a contained matrix is more than a few values, so the output of just typing `data` is more useful there.

Comment: @Toni. I've added some to my answer, I hope this clarifies things a little bit.